# How to do a jolt default operation with value fetched from a json path

Tags: jolt

{
  "a": 1
}


Lets say this is my json. Since field b is not present, i want my jolt output to be like


{
  "a":1,
  "b":1
}


b's value should be fetched from a

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can easily achieve this using the modify-default-beta operator:

```
{
"operation": "modify-default-beta",
"spec": {
  "b": "@(1,a)"
}
```

}

Basically you are defaulting b's value with a's content. If b has a value it wont overwrite it.